# When can we integrate Wiener process?

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, differential-forms

I get confused with the Itô integral.
For example, if I look at geometric Brownian motion then we say $\int \alpha X_t dW_t$ is an Itô integral, one cannot integrate it, so one uses Itô formula. Then $\int \alpha dW_t$ comes out and you can suddenly integrate it into $\alpha W_t$.
Why can't you integrate $\int \alpha X_tdW_t$ but $\int \alpha dW_t$?

Comment: Depends - what is $X_t$? A semimartingale?

Comment: $X_t$ is only defined as a stochastic process...

Comment: @Sinem Was the answer below useful? If so, please mark it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You *can* integrate $\int \alpha X_t dW_t$ (assuming $X$ is reasonably well-behaved), it just usually doesn't have a closed form solution.  There are very few cases where you do get a closed form solution.  The case where $X_t = 1$ for all $t$ is one of those cases.

It's no different from saying we can integrate $\int x dx$ to get $\frac 12 x^2$, but can't integrate $\int e^{-\frac 12 x^2} dx$: We *can* integrate the second one, it just doesn't have a closed form solution.